# Retrieve data through 2 relations (3 tables) and display it as listBox

Tags: yii2

I have this situation: 3 tables with 2 relationships (1 -> 2, 2 -> 3). I want to know how can I access data in the 1st table CRUD from the 3rd table using those two relationships.

table 1: **books**

```
book_id | book_name 
1       | Fairy tales
```

table 2: **books_authors**

```
book_authors_id | book_id | author_id
1               | 1       | 1
2               | 1       | 2
```

table 3: **authors**

```
author_id | author_name
1         | JJ
2         | KK 
3         | MM
4         | NN
```

The tables are related as follows:

```
books - books_authors      through BookAuthors 1:M, 
books_authors - authors    through AuthorsId 1:1
```

Each book may have one or more authors.

I want to display in the book's CRUD (add/modify) a listbox with **ALL the authors' names**, but **the ones already assigned to the specific book to be selected**.

In the `book\_form.php` I've tried something like:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'book_id')->listBox(
    ArrayHelper::map(BookAuthors::find()->all(),'book_id','author_id'),
    [
        'multiple' => true,
        'size' => 7,
    ]
    ) 
?>
```

... but I'm getting only the author's IDs associated with the book. Basically I want to know how can I use the second relationship in the above code, if possible.

Many thanks!

Comment: A few things. How are your relations defined? is it one M:M relationship, or two 1:M relationships? Why are your form-field on the attribute 'book_id'? and lastly why are you listing BookAuthors? That should be Authors? Maybe you should add your Model::relations() to the question..

Comment: 1. I've updated the question regarding 1:M and M:M. Since a book may have many authors, I want to keep track on a separate table (perhaps it's not the best method in Yii vs. procedural). 2. I have no clue how to link `books` and `authors` directly and take into account what's in the `books_authors` and mark them as 'selected' in the list of authors.